# How to show specific axes in a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created a figure which has 2 axes, how can I plot specific axes(eg,ax[0]) rather than plot both axes? When I input fig in the end both axes will appear together. What code should I write if I just want ax[0] be displayed for example?

```
 fig,ax=plt.subplots(2)
 x=np.linspace(1,10,100)
 ax[0].plot(x,np.sin(x))
 ax[1].plot(x,np.cos(x))
 fig
```

Comment: If you want only one axis in your figure, why bother creating 2 at the beginning? Just distinguish scenarios in which you need 1 or 2, and create a figure accordingly.

Comment: Let's say sometimes I want to display a specific axe in the figure(I dont know which one I will display in the future use when I created the figure). Is there any code to do that?

Comment: The only way I can think of would be to hide one of the axes and then to change the size of the second one to get it full size... Really doesn't feel smart at all. I would rather manage to know beforehand what I need to plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I interprete that you are using Jupyter notebook. You may then use the fact that invisble axes parts of a figure will be cropped with the `matplotlib inline` backend.

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax=plt.subplots(2);
x=np.linspace(1,10,100)
ax[0].plot(x,np.sin(x))
ax[1].plot(x,np.cos(x))
```

Now to only show the second subplot, you can set the first invisible,

```
ax[0].set_visible(False)
fig
```

[image]

If you then want to only show the first subplot, you need to set it visible again and the second one invisible

```
ax[0].set_visible(True)
ax[1].set_visible(False)
fig
```

[image]